# how to show portions of site according to locale in Rails using I18?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a question here, and i hope you can point me int he right direction...

I need to "hide" a certain portion of my site to people accessing to it from a certain language (for example, english) and i wasnt it to be visible for default locales.

can this be done?

Any idea?

I am on Rails 3, ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I18n.locale` returns the current locale.

```
if :en == I18n.locale
   # ...
end
```

Comment: and you would use this in routes.rb? or where?

Comment: You can use this in your controllers and views. To exclude a route from a specific locale, you could put a [constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) on the route's `:locale`.

Comment: I think best practice will be to add `before_filters` to your controllers which will check locale as @Stefan proposed for needed actions, and if it is forbidden one - generate Forbidden ( 403 ) response.